# Array formula behaviour inconsistent?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to use a sum with an array formula to be able to make a "sumproductif" :

my old formula :

```
 =SUMIFS(OFFSET($B$2:$B$1915;0;$Z$22);$L$2:$L$1915;$Y$3;$B$2:$B$1915;X4)
```

I replaced it with

```
{=SUM(OFFSET($B$2:$B$1915;0;$Z$22)*($L$2:$L$1915=$Y$3)*($B$2:$B$1915=X4))}
```

Which gives me the exact same result as above

However, when I try to multiply by another column that contains only numbers,

```
{=SUM(OFFSET($B$2:$B$1915;0;$Z$22)*($W$2:$W$1915)*($L$2:$L$1915=$Y$3)*($B$2:$B$1915=X4))}
```

Yields me an error. Any idea of what I did wrong?

I even tried to make it very clear for excel :

```
{=SUM(OFFSET($B$2:$B$1915;0;$Z$22)*(($W$2:$W$1915)*1)*($L$2:$L$1915=$Y$3)*($B$2:$B$1915=X4))}
```

which didn't help

My column W does only contain numbers or empty cells (at the exact same rows than the other columns at play here)

Comment: Are they truly empty cells in that column or are they the results of formula where it is an empty string; `""`

Comment: An empty string. I replaced them with 0 and it worked. So yeah I probably got caught in the whole pitfall of empty-not-empty, which is not my first time